# Restrict access on specific database from windows users

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a easy way to deny all access from Management Studio to a specific db **except** from sa and 1 another SQL user that will be used to access db from a remote app ?

i'd like that users connecting to Management studio with a windows login account would not be able to open/browse this db, only user connecting with sa or this other SQL user could.

Thx.

Edit

On the global user settings in management studio :

The user is allowed on all db except the one

[image]

In the specific db, on the user :

[image]

[image]

In management studio, the user can still open db, browse table column, select table, update table etc...

Comment: You can't really restrict for a specific client tool, e.g. only in Management Studio. But you can deny access to a specific database for specific users, from all client tools - would that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it would. You're right, Management studio is not relevant here. Is it possible to setup kind of a white list (grant access to specific user) and by default deny access to all other SQL & Windows user ?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are denied by default in SQL Server. So long as no one grants any permissions to the User directly, any groups the User is a part of directly, or adds the Login of the User to the `SysAdmin` Server Role, then they won't have access to the database.

If you really wanted to be explicit, you can specifically add the User to the [`sp_denydatareader` and `sp_denydatawriter` roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16) for that database too. This will take precedent over if anyone grants permissions to the User that would've otherwise provided access to the database. To globally apply it to all Windows Users, you can apply it to the Windows AD Group `Domain Users`.

Comment: I try to do this but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I try to do this but unsuccessfully. On the specific database, i add the user to security => user and in his properties, i set db_denydatareader & db_denydatawriter in SERVER ROLES. I set his default schema to db_denydatareader in GENERAL. The user can still browse db table through Management Studio.

Comment: @seb I don't understand. I find it easiest to manage the User permissions on the Login itself in the `User Mapping` section of the properties window. "*i set db_denydatareader & db_denydatawriter in SERVER ROLES.*" - There's no such server roles with those names, only database roles. Maybe you mean you set them in the `User Mapping` section of the Login's properties, like I mentioned. "*I set his default schema to db_denydatareader.*" - Again, this is not a schema, so this doesn't make sense to me. Maybe add some screenshots of the properties window(s) you're working in, to your Post.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to translate Management studio from french to English. I added some screenshot in the first post. Thx